Lucene behaviour boolean query
I am experiencing weird behaviour with a BooleanQuery.
Let's say my index looks like this:
text: bla bla2 moreinfo hi
user: 123

Then I have the following code:
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser('text', new StandardAnalyzer());   
Query q = parser.parse(searchString);
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(q, Occur.MUST) 
            .build();

With this code, if I search for 'bl' it will give me a result (match on 'bla'). Now I add a user constraint to this booleanQuery, like this:
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser('text', new StandardAnalyzer());   
Query q = parser.parse(searchString);
TermQuery userQuery = new TermQuery(new Term('user','123'));
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(q, Occur.MUST) 
            .add(userQuery, Occur.MUST)
            .build();

Now, suddenly 'bl' does not return anything. However, searching for 'bla' or 'bl*' does.
So it seems like the behaviour of the query 'q' changes because I added another clause to the booleanQuery.
I am trying to understand why this happens? Ps. I prefer to be able to search on 'bl' instead of having to use 'bl*'.

"With this code, if I search for 'bl' it will give me a result (match on 'bla')." Are you sure? The code in the question has a syntax error. When I correct that error, the query returns no hits. (A) Can you double-check the exact code which returns that match on bla? (B) Can you clarify exactly how you are indexing your data - because if you are indexing your data using the standard analyzer, then bl is not in the resulting index as a searchable token - and therefore searching for bl should find no hits.

And just to clarify, what version of Lucene are you using? And this is Java, right (so "text" is valid syntax for strings; not 'text' which is a syntax error`).
